# Update azure token on one place for multiple stations without domain access

Tags: python, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have multiple stations without domain access running on local user, that query Azure DevOps using a token.

According to my organization policy, this token expires every 3 months and it requires to update all stations with the new token.

I would like to update the token for all stations at once, I thought on:

1. Use Azure SQL DB
2. Use Azure blob - a bit problematic since it is open for all but very easy to update

Are there any other options to achieve this without the domain access?

The stations runs Powershell script which runs a Python script - both need the token

Comment: are you talking about PAT?

Comment: Yes, PAT - Personal access token

Comment: did you check the REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

Comment: I did but I'm unauthorized

Comment: maybe the organization policy is blocking you from generating PATs , you need to check with the administrator

Comment: are you using a service principal that is authorized to generate PAT and call microsoft graph api?

Comment: I'm able to generate PAT using the portal but not through the Rest API. However, doesn't this requires a PAT to build the request?

Comment: if it is not working using rest then it is a permission issue with the service principal, you can try it on test tenant to confirm

Answer (score 1):

You can manage PAT using the REST API and Microsoft graph:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops

and schedule a task in the local machines to request a new one just before the expiration (90 days)

Comment: Thanks, but that might be tricky.
1. I should already have a PAT for send the request
2. In case a PAT generated successfully how does it updated on the stations?

Comment: you should use the new one in revoke the old.